# animating registration page android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to add animation to my registration page. I have 6 EditTexts and I want them to come one by one from right to left. I'm new to android, someone help me please. 
[Screenshot registration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTdZY.png)

Comment: With 'LayoutTransition' default animations can be applied whenever items are added to or removed from the container. To specify custom animations, use the setAnimator() method.Refer following link for more details - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom animation xmls and place inside anim folder inside resources folder:

left_swipe.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
```

right_swipe.xml

```
 <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
```

You can start animation like :

```
RightAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Screen.this, R.anim.right_swipe);
ScreenAnimation.startAnimation(RightAnim );
```

Answer (score 0):

Plz make sure your animation xml file under res>anim
This is for `slide_in_left`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
            android:duration="2500"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

and this is for `slide_in_right`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
            android:duration="2500"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

in your java code

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(RegisterActivity.this, R.anim.slide_in_left);
            a.reset();                 
            etusername.clearAnimation();
            etusername.startAnimation(a);   

Animation b = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(RegisterActivity.this, R.anim.slide_in_right);
            b.reset();                 
            etpassword.clearAnimation();
            etpassword.startAnimation(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

left to right animation:

**leftToRight.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

right to left animation:

**rightToLeft**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

write below code in your activity class

```
private Animation m_animationLeft;
private Animation m_animationRight;

m_animationLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.leftToRight);
m_animationRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rightToLeft);

editTextOne.startAnimation(m_animationLeft);
m_animationLeft.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation p_animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation p_animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation p_animation)
                    {
                        // Start animation on another edittext . If you want to perform animation one by one edittext
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
```